# SQL query in RStudio not working (odbc)

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I am trying to run a query in RStudio but instead of table view, getting error 42000 933, query not properly ended. I belive this is linked with syntax that Oracle is not accepting.

Please find below an example:

```
rawdata <- sqlQuery(con, "Select *
from schema
        where some_data like '19%'
        and var_1 not in (
        'Option1',
        'Option2')
        and var_2 not in  ('one', 'two')
        and var_3 <> 'OPTIONAL'
        order by var_1, var_2;
        ")
```

I changed name of variables so some inconsistency may occur but this is not a clue. Can anyone help me with that or give some hints where to search for?

Comment: Oracle does not like semicolons at the end of statements.

Answer (score 0):

`Schema` is a reserved [keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm). So, if you can't change the table name (which would be advisable), you'll have to escape it. **edit:** You also forgot the `by` in `order by` :

```
Select *
from "schema"
where some_data like '19%'
and var_1 not in (
                    'Option1',
                    'Option2')
and var_2 not in  ('one', 'two')
and var_3 <> 'OPTIONAL'
order by var_1, var_2;
```

Comment: This is not a table name. I made up it wrongly, but let's say it is any other word. I think this error refer to some other things, like no possibility of using aliases.

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed this statement, but run it properly in RStudio. Thank you fro helping me but problem still occurs.

Comment: I have found what was generating a problem. ; on the end of statement.